# Joining two tables with in clause

Tags: mysql, sql, django

So I have two models containing primary key 'User'

```
class Reviews(models.Model):
    subject_user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='reviewed_user')

class Friendship(models.Model):
    head_user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='followed')
```

Now I want to find all the reviews of users who are also in the Friendsip.head_user... Something like this

```
SELECT * FROM reviews JOIN friendship WHERE reviews.subject_user_id IN friendship.head_user_id

OR

SELECT * FROM reviews JOIN friendship ON reviews.subject_user_id = friendship.head_user_id
```

How can I do this in Django. The SQL(might not be perfect) is just to explain what i'm trying to do.

Comment: Django ORM is a little bit different then SQL. How should output data look like?

Comment: Okay, what i need is list of Reviews objects and all the corresponding User objects(every review has a subject_user).

Answer (score 0):

use select related

```
Reviews.objects.all().select_related('friendship__ head_user_id')
```

or read on [lookups that span relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

or maybe this will be helpfull: '[F expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/queries/#django.db.models.F)'

Comment: In your answer, you used `.all()` for the reviews and ignored the `subject_user` part. In reality I have many another fields in the Reviews model, like `tail_user = models.ForeignKey(User)` etc etc... So should it be like `Reviews.objects.all().select_related('friendship__ head_user_id','reviews__subject_user_id')`

Comment: This answer is very misleading - or even wrong. `select_related` does not in any way add columns from foreign models into the base objects. All it does is make the already-existing foreign key relationship more efficient.

Comment: as i understood he just wanted to have the foreign key(joined), and not adding new culomns, select_related does that..

Comment: sorry if I wasn't very clear with the question. I reasked it with example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857826/join-two-tables-containing-same-foreign-key-in-django)