# JOIN two tables containing same foreign key in Django

Tags: mysql, sql, django

So I have two models containing primary key 'User'

```
class Reviews(models.Model):
    subject_user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='reviewed_user')
    actor = models.ForeignKey(User)                         ## irrelavent 
    text = models.TextField()

class Friendship(models.Model):
    head_user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='followed')
    tail_user = models.ForeignKey(User)                     ## irrelavent
```

Now I want to find all the reviews of users who are also in the `Friendsip.head_user`. For example, say **User '1'** wrote a review each for **User '3'** and **User '5'**

```
Reviews:
subject_user_id     actor_id     text
3                   1            LoremIpsum1
5                   1            LoremIpsum2

Friendship:
head_user           tail_user
3                   9
8                   9      ### Irrelavent
```

Now I output should be reviews object corresponding to 'LoremIpsum1' i.e. the review object whose subject_user is also present in `Friendship.head_user`. I tried the following

```
reviews = Reviews.objects.all().select_related('friendship__head_user')
```

But it is giving me all the reviews

**Edit:**

This is how I insert the review:

```
review, created = Reviews.object.get_or_create(subject_user=target, actor=actor)
review.text = NewReviewText
review.save()
```

Comment: How do you already have the `Review` for "LoremIpsum1", or the `Friendship` for "8"?

Comment: I didn't exactly get what you didn't get... `User '1'` wrote a review "LoremIpsum1" for `User '3'` , so i already have the entry there.

Comment: No, the entry is present in the database. But how do *you* have it in *code*?

Comment: sorry for being a noob but can't interpret what you're asking. The code of how I insert a review? (Edited the question for that) :/ #sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should work:

```
heads = (f.head_user for f in Friendship.objects.all())
reviews = Reviews.objects.all().filter("subject_user__in"=heads)
```

First you grab all the head users in `Friendship`s and then find all their reviews, which seems to match your requirement:

> I want to find all the reviews of users who are also in the `Friendship.head_user`

The reason you can't use [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) is that it expects that there will be an explicit relationship between the two models, which in your case there *is not*. There is no foreign key defined between a `Review` and a `Friendship`, so in this case the most optimal way is probably what I've proposed.

However, until you've tested this in anger and done some analysis to confirm is is a critical slow point in your system, I'd heed the words of Donald Knuth:

> We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: yes. that's exactly what i want. But Is this optimal? like the best way?

Comment: "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil" - Donald Knuth

Comment: This uses a python list generator and leaves a lot of the data access up to the ORM. Until you've tried this in anger and done some analysis to confirm is is a critical slow pointin your system, I'd recommend this for the time being.

Comment: you(or should I say Donald Knuth) just opened my eyes... Thank you.

Comment: I really wish I could take credit for the quote, but alas I cannot. however, the flip side is that you should always be on the look out for inefficiencies, when they occur. Consider a method that takes 10 seconds to run and could be sped up 100 times - if its only run once a day is it worth optimising or are there other more pressing things you couldo?