# Django - queryset for multiple models that related with foreignkey

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have models.py like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    ...

class Categories(models.Model):
   category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   post_id = models.ForeignKey(Post)

class Tags(models.Model):
  tag = = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  tag_id = models.ForeignKey(Post)
```

How do I get the all the related objects if given the author id. 
eg. In the view.py

```
def AllPost(request, userid):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(author=userid)
    for post in Posts:
         category = Categories.filter(post_id = post.id)
         tag = Tags.filter(post_id = post.id)
```

The problem of the function above will causes extra query for each of the post. Is there any way to call all the objects in single query??

Comment: possible duplicate of [JOIN two tables containing same foreign key in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857826/join-two-tables-containing-same-foreign-key-in-django)

Answer (score 1):

For **django >= 1.4**, use [prefecth_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related).

```
class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    ...

class Categories()models.Model:
   category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='categories')
```

```
def get_all_posts(request, user_id):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(author=user_id).prefetch_related('categories')
    for post in posts:
         categories = post.categories
```

*(Note: some code errors fixed.)*

For **django < 1.4**, you can use [django_prefetch](https://github.com/ionelmc/django-prefetch) plugin.

Comment: But how about the Tags? Can i prefetch_related more than one objects? like `prefetch_related('categories', 'tags')`?

Answer (score 1):

How about like this:

```
Categories= Category.objects.filter(tag_id__author=userid) #assuming userid is an User object like for example: request.User
Tags= Tags.objects.filter(post_id__auther=userid)
```

if you want to get both category and tags from `Post` in single query, then you will get ValuesQuerySet from following query:

```
data= Post.objects.filter(auther=userid).values_list('category', 'tags') #or .values_list('category__category', 'tags__tag')
```